# PHP: How to echo an URL link without displaying the whole url address

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

How do we echo this url link so it displays a link named `View` instead of the long generated url address? It's this currently I'm using:

`echo($value->url."<br>");`

The output of the code above would give me the whole url address, so can someone writes how if I want it to be a simple `link` named `View` ? Thanks..

P.S The above code currently doesn't display the url in link, I want it to be a click-able link named `View`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised that nobody answered with the 'Cake' way to do this. For a straight link, you'll have to tinker a little as the helper expects a path relative to controllers, but it's not difficult. It's the best way to do it if your url is internal to the site, i.e. an action/view handled by CakePHP.

```
<?php echo $html->link('View', $value->url); ?>
```

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1442/link

edit:

...and of course a better way to do it in PHP would be to leverage the double quote parsing -

```
<?php echo "<a href='$url'>View</a>"; ?>
```

or, if you want to be picky,

```
<?php echo "<a href=\"$url\">View</a>"; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Leo, I'm contemplating to tick this as my answer as it both CakePHP and PHP style give the same result I wonder why we need to use a helper, although I'm using the Cake style now as you mentioned. Some people has said that the helper is a useless feature in Cake. Sometimes looking at the long helper coding makes everything more complicated. I wonder what else do you know more about this since I'm new to Cake about 2 months now..?

Comment: When I started using Cake I asked the same questions - Google "poking sticks in wasps nests" and you'll find some. I was much less experienced then, but I still find it hard to answer the question convincingly. It's up to you whether or not you use the helpers, and some of them don't seem to help much ($form->end() is a good example). I can only say that now I use them as much as possible....

Comment: ...Perhaps it's a semantic realignment - I'm more a programmer than an HTMLer and I feel more comfortable this way. Some helpers, like Form, offer huge benefits in things like security. The bottom line is that you're using CakePHP as a 'PHP helper' so it would be churlish not to use it in the same way for HTML.

Comment: Since I'm already using a helper in my code, I'm changing the arrangement of ticking my answer. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 3):

```
echo '<a href="'.$value->url.'">View</a>';
```

Answer (score 1):

`echo '<a href="'.$value->url.'">View</a>';`

Comment: Thanks, I picked the answered first, sorry. Both are same working like a charm. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php echo '<a href="',$value->url,'">View</a>"'; ?>
```

use some html in it.

Answer (score 1):

this way worked for me:

```
<td><?php print "<a href='$row[website]'> go </a>"; ?></td>
```